# How can I remove the badge number if I click on close button in push notification?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios-4.2, apple-push-notifications, badge

I am working with push notifications. When I get a notification it comes with 2 button, view and close. If I click on view it opens the app and when I click the close button it does nothing but a badge number appears on the app icon. Then when I open my app again that badge number should disappear but it doesn't. How can I remove that badge number if user clicks on app icon? Thanx

Answer (score 40, accepted):

put the following code somewhere in your applicationDidFinishLaunching or applicationDidBecomeActive.

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is omit the `badge` key from your remote notification so that [any badge number currently shown is removed](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html). If you want a badge to show up if the user taps View, you can set a badge number using `[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber`.

But I'm not sure why you'd want to do this.

Comment: what if user click close button? i have done that view button clicked part before.

Comment: The notification will remove the badge, so there wil be no badge if the user taps Close.  As mentioned [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html), "If \[the `badge` property\] is absent, any badge number currently shown is removed."